# What was the family relationship between British neo-Nazi politician John Tyndall and the 19th century physicist of the same name?

Tags: political-history, 19th-century, britain

[John Tyndall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Tyndall_(politician)) was a neo-Nazi British politician who chaired the National Front and who was the chairman of the British National Party from 1982 to 1999. According to [his obituary in the Daily Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/obituaries/1494381/John-Tyndall.html), he was a descendant of the 19th century physicist John Tyndall. That ancestor was a "Social Darwinist" associate of Herbert Spencer and Thomas Huxley in the [X Club](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Club). What exactly was the family relationship between the two men?

Comment: Wikikedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Tyndall#Private_life) says the physicist Tyndall (1820-1893) had no children.

Comment: Many thanks for this. It seems the Daily Telegraph were using the word "ancestor" in an unusual way or were mistaken. [This source](http://www.ulsternation.org.uk/a_rock_amongst_willows.htm) says the physicist John Tyndall was the neo-Nazi's "great-great uncle", but I would still be grateful for more details.